# SSRS Multiple pages in 1 report

Tags: reporting-services

I have built a report called "TeamDraw" and my report populates fields based on a parameter 'TeamQuotaId' which groups similar 'TeamNames' . I need to know if in SSRS I can have the same report repeated for each 'TeamQuotaid' so if I have three 'Teamquotas' '12345' '67890' 12589'. I would need the first page to show the report based on quota '12345' the second page would show the report based on quota '67890' and the third page would show the report based on quota '12589'. I know this sounds confusing but any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a report template for a single quota (Report A) that accepts a single quota as a parameter.
2. Create a parent report that can accept multiple quota ids ( Report B ).
3. In Report B, Create a tablix which contains a single column. In the column cell, insert Report A as a subreport. Add a row group for your set of quota IDs. Set the Quota parameter for the subreport to the row group quota ID value.
4. Right-click the row group you created, and go to Group Properties. On the Page Breaks tab, choose "Between each instance of a group".
5. Now each quota ID report gets printed on its own page.

Comment: So the subreport im using takes three parametes ]ID as int, @]Temptables as bit, IsDrawId as bit how do I populate these parameters in the subreport?

Comment: In the properties of the subreport, there is a Parameters tab which you can populate with hard-coded values or values from your parent report, including group-level values (so if you group by QuotaID, you pass Group!QuotaID and it sets it to the correct QuotaID for each row.)

Comment: Thanks totally helped out